# Flutter DB Backup While Using Sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, backup, database-backups, sqflite

I'm working on a flutter project. I want to extract and add the database for backup, but I haven't been able to do it for days. I'm thinking about how I can do this. I wonder if I can do this. Is this possible? If not, should I do it? If this is not possible when using SQLite, what should I use?

I tried everything but I couldn't do it. If anyone has a sample project, please share it with me.

Comment: [`VACUUM INTO`](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) is probably the simplest way.

Comment: Do you have a sample code or a resource where I can learn how to do it?

Comment: It's just a SQL statement. See the linked documentation.